# Don't use prepared statements in Laravel Eloquent ORM?

Tags: sql, laravel, prepared-statement, eloquent, infinidb

Can I have Eloquent ORM run a query without using prepared statements? Or do I have to use `whereRaw()`?

I need to use a raw query because I'm trying to interact with InfiniDB, which lacks support for prepared statements from PHP. At any rate, all queries will be using internally generated data, not user input so it should not be a security issue.

Answer (score 1):

For anything other than `SELECT` you can use [`unprepared()`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Connection.php#L378)

```php
DB::unprepared($sql);
```

For an unprepared `SELECT` you can use plain PDO `query()` by getting access to active PDO connection through [`getPdo()`](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Connection.php#L780)

```php
$pdo = DB::getPdo();
$query = $pdo->query($sql);
$result = $query->fetchAll();
```

Comment: So essentially there's no easy way to do what I need to do - I'll just have to manually write out the query?

Comment: @peterm Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51838922/how-can-i-convert-many-statement-mysql-to-laravel-eloquent

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy way to do it. In the file `config/database.php` you can specify options for php PDO like so:

```
'mysql_unprepared' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PROXY_PORT', '6033'),
        'username' => env('DB_CACHED_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_CACHED_PASSWORD', ''),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? [
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,
        ] : [],
        'modes'  => [
            'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
            'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
            'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
            'NO_ZERO_DATE',
            'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
            'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
        ],
    ],
```

As you can see, there is an option `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` which, when set to `true`, will do a prepare-like action on application level and send the query unprepared instead. I didn't figure PDO had this option until I had already created an extension for Laravel's mysql driver just to intercept select queries and do unprepared `mysqli` queries instead so that `ProxySql` could cache them.

So this answer could have been a lot more complicated. Cheers.