# PDO Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2030 with MemSQL setting via MySQL Driver in 'database.php'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel-5, singlestore

Is this related to my VPS host not supporting SSE 4.2 or related to my PHP framework (Laravel) or my CMS (October) or some other MemSQL/MySQL driver issue? I tried several remediation techniques, too many to list here. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: I thought it might be a PDO fetch class issue but configuring different fetch class settings didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error, because you are trying (or Laravel is trying) to execute a prepared statement. Unfortunately, MemSQL doesn't seem to support some subset of prepared statements protocol that laravel uses.

I found this question wrt whether Laravel can be configured to not use prepared statements. I have very little knowledge about Laravel, so I can't tell if the answer there is helpful or not.

[Don't use prepared statements in Laravel Eloquent ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296029/dont-use-prepared-statements-in-laravel-eloquent-orm)

Comment: Thanks for the response that's really helpful. Any ideas where to start editing in Laravel Dev source? I'll ping the Laravel team asap. Just out of curiosity could the solution to this potentially come from the MySQL client driver itself? Thanks again.

Comment: I reached out to MemSQL via Twitter regarding future support for prepared statements and will report back with answer asap.